# TCP connection behind NAT

Tags: tcp, udp, nat

Two clients behind different NATs.

```
Clinet A --- NAT ----Internet ----- NAT -------Client B.
```

Can I use  UDP for hole punching,After success,I Got the ip and port after NAT.
Can I use the port for TCP connection? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. TCP ports and UDP ports are completely different namespaces.